# A term that describes the scenario when there is at one least trending data set for data sets over same time range

Tags: statistics, slope

Given that I have 2 separate sets of plotted data points. Both data points run over the same time interval. Assume that at any given time interval, both datasets are either trending or one is trending and the other is not trending. Also at no time interval do both date sets range simultaneously.

My question: Is there statistical or math term that defines such a scenario? The term must not perfectly define the scenario but in some way relate to it.

Comment: A numerical example makes it easier to understand.

Comment: For example: looking at the financial markets. Let’s say we have 2 stocks, A and B. We now look at the daily price chart over the last one year for both stocks. Assuming for significant amount of  days of the year either stock A or B is trending or both stocks are trending. Rarely over the one year time frame did both A and B range on the same day.

Comment: Is there a formula, term or word that describes, calculate or explains the concept I described in my example above.